# Replace pattern with the number of matches so far

Tags: replacement, indexing

I want to replace a **n**-th pattern match in an expression with **n**. This is a very simple task, though it appears very hard to find an elegant implementation.

For example, with input

```
inp = {x, y, z, x, y, x, x, z}
```

I wish to compute, replacing pattern `x`,

```
{1, y, z, 2, y, 3, 4, z}
```

Preferably, I'd like to access the index **n** in the replacement rule.
E.g. something like

```
Func[inp, x :> Symbol[m<>ToString@#]& ]

>>> {m1, y, z, m2, y, m3, m4, z}
```

How can I achieve this? It's trivial using `Count` and a `For` loop, but is very un-stylistic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using the Increment operator:

```
(*In[1]:= *)i = 1;

(*In[2]:= *)inp = {x, y, z, x, y, x, x, z};

(*In[3]:= *)inp /. x :> i++

(*Out[3]= {1, y, z, 2, y, 3, 4, z}*)
```

Hopefully it's obvious how this can be extended to your example using Symbol.

Comment: If you start with `i=0` and then use `inp /. x :> ++i`, then at the end the index `i` contains the number of elements matched (instead of one more). Also, if you use `inp /. x :> m[++i]`, then you get an indexing as desired (but without using `Symbol`, which may not be necessary).

Comment: A pity to have to use a variable, but it's still quite concise

Comment: @Roman quite right, `m[ind]` is much more elegant, thanks!

Comment: @AntiEarth with `Block` you can make `i` a local variable, so you don't need to worry about polluting the name space.